# Custom strategy Oauth authentication using Passport JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am attempting to authenticate with Passport using this API given at: https://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/ivlelapi/Android.  User session data should be stored as well.

From the document, it appears that the authentication process is a simpler version of Oauth:

1. The app server redirects the user to authorizing website's login page.
2. The login page returns a successful token
3. User details can then be retrieved using this token

However, the OAuth strategy for passport seems to require a consumer callback, and requires a more elaborate process using 2 tokens.

Is there any way OAuth can be used in this instance?  I have explored using passport-local, checking for only the user parameter (if user exists, to add user to DB), but it does not seem to accept other parameters.

Alternatively, should Passport JS be necessary in such an instance?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use bearer token or JWT. Once user success to authenticated, the endpoint could return token in JSON format and then you can store it in local. The use of bearer or JWT token it allow session less authenticate, which mean that the token will contain information about expiry and user id.

I suggest that you should use passport and pick the strategy that fit your need, other than reimplement it.

[Passport JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt)

[Passport Bearer Token](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer)